# Character Strings in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

How can I extract characters before a `#` in R? My string is `yet#rt` and I just want to extract `yet`. `substring` is fine but the stuff before `#` is of differing length, so I can't use it here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `gsub()` to strip off the # symbol and everything after it

```
x <- c("apple#pie", "banana#split")
gsub("#.*$","", x)
# [1] "apple"  "banana"
```

Comment: hi ..how would it be if I want to split by a dot?

Comment: The gsub pattern takes a regular expression and dots are actually special characters in regular expressions so you need to escape it. You can do that with: `x <- c("apple.pie", "banana.split"); gsub("\\..*$","", x)`

Answer (score 3):

In R, the `"#"` is generally considered to be a comment character, so several functions to get data into R, like `scan` and `read.table`, have a `comment.char` argument that tells R to ignore everything after that character is encountered.

Here's an approach with `scan`:

```
my.strings <- c("yet#rt", "blah#rt", "meh#rt")
scan(what = "character", text = my.strings, comment.char = "#")
# Read 3 items
# [1] "yet"  "blah" "meh"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strsplit`. How about this??

```
strsplit("Good#Bad","#")[[1]][1]
[1] "Good"
```

Comment: why doesnt that work if i take something like yet.txt and try to split it into yet and text and then get only the yet?

Comment: the second argument of the function is to specify which character to use for splitting. For dot you have to add escape characters.if you write `strsplit("yet.txt","\\.")[[1]][1]` it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^#]*(?=#)
```

You can try this simple regex to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possibility

```
library(stringr)
my.string <- "yet#rt"
str_sub(string = my.string, end = str_locate(my.string,"#")[1]-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `beg2char` (beginning to character) function in the **qdap** package that I maintain is made for this sort of thing:

```
library(qdap)

x <- c("apple#pie", "banana#split")
beg2char(x, "#")
## [1] "apple"  "banana"
```

For other characters (you asked about a period):

```
x <- c("apple.pie", "banana.split.")
beg2char(x, ".")
## [1] "apple"  "banana
```